# Unity URP light weaker than built-in

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've recently added URP to my project. The problem I'm having is all the lights are way weaker than they used to be including area and spot. I am using a spot light as a flashlight for my character and the only way I can make it so the flashlight actually shows something is by turning up the intensity by a lot like a 1000 minimum and that casts a beam of light which is not nice because getting close to objects turns them white instead of actually showing them up like it used to I would like if someone knows what can I do about it

Comment: check this link: https://forum.unity.com/threads/light-intensity-in-built-in-vs-urp.1123735/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the color space to linear instead of gamma under
"Edit>Project Settings>Player>Other Settings>Color Space>Gamma/Linear"
This worked for me in order to make it so moving close to objects wont make them in the color of the light.